# show button in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am downloading some large files through one of the cell in the my datagrid.
I want to show Pause/stop downloading button inside datagrid when downloading starts.
I have added the button in the datagrid by setting it's visibility to hidden. but i cannot find a way to set it's visibility to visible in cs file.
Can any one please guide me how can i achieve this?

Xaml file:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="125">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Button Name="StopBtn"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="StopButton_Click">
<Button.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="stop.png"/>
<Button.Background>
</Button>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property in the in the cs file and bind to it from xaml

`public Visibility StopBtnVisibilty`

`<Button Name="StopBtn"  Visibility="{Binding StopBtnVisibilty, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="StopButton_Click">`

You can assign the property to be Visible or Hidden from the code-behind and propagate the change to the xaml.